# AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE in django

Tags: django

**models.py**

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, unique=True)
```

**settings.py:**

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'project.pm.UserProfile'
```

views.py

```
   if request.method == 'POST':
        r = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if r.is_valid():
            team = Team(name=request.POST.get('team'))
            team.save()
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=request.POST.get('email'),
                                 email=request.POST.get('email'),
                                 password=request.POST.get('password'))
            user.get_profile.team = team.id
            user.save()
```

I had error on line `user.get_profile.team = team.id`

> AttributeError at /register
>   'instancemethod' object has no
>   attribute 'team'

***How can I fix this error?***

Comment: AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE and get_profile() are deprecated: https://github.com/django/django/commit/70a0de37d132e5f1514fb939875f69649f103124

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`User.get_profile` is a method, so you'll need to call it like so:

```
user.get_profile().team
```

Comment: UserProfile matching query does not exist.I need to make yourself a profile?

Comment: Sure. The other way(and maybe better) add extra fields to User is inheritance: http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/

Comment: Obviously, you figured this out, but you also need to add *user.get_profile().save()*.